# Module rank and dimension of its embedding

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do you know which rings $R$ and fields $F$ satisfy

> Given a free $R$-module $M$, $\textrm{rank}(M) = \dim_F(F\otimes_{R}M)$?

E.g., $(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q})$ seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give a sense to the right hand side, you need a ring homomorphism $R\to F$. Then the equality holds. Actually, if $\{ e_i\}_i$ is a basis of $M$ over $R$, then $\{ 1\otimes e_i\}_i$ is a basis of $F\otimes_R M$ over $F$.

Comment: How do you prove the linear independence of $\{1\otimes e_i\}$?